# Animation on iOS got stuck

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to animate a rotating element, this works great on android but on iOS it gets stuck at a rotation of 90 degree.

I want to do the animation with CSS to keep the javascript code clean. Also javascript animations can block other javascript code i want to run.

```
@keyframes rotate-element {
    0%  {transform: rotate(0);}
    25% {transform: rotate(90);}
    50% {transform: rotate(180);}
    75% {transform: rotate(270);}
    100%{transform: rotate(360);}
}

#clock {
    animation-name: rotate-element;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

My page looks like this

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" actionBarHidden="true" backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true" id="main">
  <StackLayout>
        <Image id="clock" src="~/Images/clock.png"></Image>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Which versionof tns you hve installed and on which iOS you are testing - I have tested your case and it works for me on iOS 9.3

Comment: I am testing on an iPhone 6 / iOS 9.3 Simulator

Comment: Added the xml page

Comment: I am experiencing a different behavior - the animation is running but at 360 degrees on iOS the value is not reset and the image makes additional full 0-to-360 spin. Will log this as an issue here where you can track its solution  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2177